# Making multiple queries to posgresql database through R shiny UI

Tags: r, postgresql, shiny

I am building a Shiny dashboard that will allow me to select certain data from my postgresql database. I am new to shiny and postgresql so I appreciate your input on this. I am aiming at having a dynamic input from User, say click to select a  name, a type, then the location for a certain data. And that the user can select it from a 3 selectinput widgets. The process of selecting the items will allow query of the data in the database. Lets say I have 7 names, 2 types and 3 locations.. so selecting a name, then a type, then a location will give me a part of the data.
This is what my initial code looks like, but it does not give me any data showing up. I checked the connection and its working, it just doesn't can not find the data I am looking for plotting and displaying so I get an empty dashboard with no table or plot. Any idea how to go about this?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(fpp)
library(plotly)
library(sp)
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(DBI)
library(pool)

#####


pool <- dbPool(drv = dbDriver("PostgreSQL", max.con = 100), user = "user", password = "pswd", host = "localhost", port = 5432, dbname = "people", idleTimeout = 3600000)

##list of people names
All<-tbl(pool, "table")
All%>%group_by(name)
names_All<- dbGetQuery(pool, "SELECT name FROM table GROUP BY name") ## list of names another way
type_grouped<- dbGetQuery(pool, "SELECT type FROM table GROUP BY type")
loc_grouped<- dbGetQuery(pool, "SELECT location FROM table GROUP BY location") 

####

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        inputId = "name",
        label = " name",
        choices = names_All,
        selected = 1,
      ),
      selectInput(
        inputId = "type",
        label = " type",
        choices = type_grouped,
        selected = 1,
  
      ),
      selectInput(
        inputId = "location",
        label = " location",
        choices = loc_grouped,
        selected = 1,
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("graph", plotOutput("plot")),
        tabPanel("Table", dataTableOutput("table"))
      )
    )
)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  selectedData <- reactive({
    req(input$name)
    req(input$type)
    req(input$location)
    query <- glue::glue_sql(
      "SELECT * FROM table
       WHERE name IN ({name*})
       AND type IN ({type*})
       AND location IN ({location*});",
      name = input$name,
      type = input$type,
      location=input$location,
      .con = pool)
    outp <- as.data.frame(dbGetQuery(pool, query))
    outp

  })

   
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(  data = selectedData(),
                   options = list(pageLength = 14),
                    rownames = FALSE)
  
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot( data = selectedData(), aes(x = date, y = name )) + geom_point()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[App running result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VKih.png)

[image: second error imgae]

Comment: When you state `names_All<- dbGetQuery(pool, "SELECT name FROM table GROUP BY name") ` where is table defined?  Also, you have a typo: `req(inputname)` should be `req(input$name)`

Comment: Your SQL is not correct as you have two `WHERE` clauses which should have raised an error. Check console for messages.

Comment: @ YBS The table is the name of my table in the database 'people' specified in pool. So I don't have to declare it as a variable. Thanks for the note on the typo, I must have accidently delete it while typing in, but its all corrected now still no data.

@Parfait its also a typo I just fixed it and still no data showing.

Comment: Please [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65517000/edit) your post with actual code and not typos. We need to see *how* you fixed it. Also, post any errors that output to console.

Comment: @Parfait thanks for pointing out I can edit the post. I had no idea I can do that, I fixed the typos. And re-run the code, nothing happened I get an empty table and plot. The selector choices are working though as I can see the options. But that does not change the data I want to select from the database. I attached the image in the edited post in the App running result link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider integrating a submit button to trigger processing of server code via an [**`eventReactive`**](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.3/observeEvent.html) call. This even helps user understand the flow of form controls and processing. Also, right now you use SQL's `IN` redundantly since input choices are only single values. But use `multiple=TRUE` argument in `selectInput()` to adjust that (with note to user).

**User Interface**

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        inputId = "name",
        label = " name",
        choices = names_All,
        selected = 1
      ),
      selectInput(
        inputId = "type",
        label = " type",
        choices = type_grouped,
        selected = 1  
      ),
      selectInput(
        inputId = "location",
        label = " location",
        choices = loc_grouped,
        selected = 1
      ),
      actionButton("submit", "Submit")        # NEW SUBMIT BUTTON
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("graph", plotOutput("plot")),
        tabPanel("Table", dataTableOutput("table"))
      )
    )
  )
)
```

**Server Function**

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  name_pick <- reactive({ req(input$name) })
  type_pick <- reactive({ req(input$type) })
  location_pick <- reactive({ req(input$location) }) 

  selectedData <- eventReactive(input$submit, { # INITIATE ON submit
    query <- "SELECT *                        
              FROM table
              WHERE name = ?name
                AND type = ?type
                AND location = ?location;"

    stmt <- DBI::sqlInterpolate(pool, 
                                query,
                                name = name_pick(),
                                type = type_pick(),
                                location = location_pick())

    outp <- dbGetQuery(pool, stmt)
  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(data = selectedData(),
                  options = list(pageLength = 14),
                  rownames = FALSE)
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = selectedData(), aes(x = date, y = name )) + 
       geom_point()
  })
  
}
```

Also, try avoiding [`SELECT *`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful) and explicitly define needed table and graph columns in specific order to control output of your Shiny result. Plus, it helps with readability and maintainability of code.

Comment: Thank you Parfait. I managed to edit my code as per your comment. I can see changes happening the console when I click submit. However, I got this error, ***Warning: Error in eval: attempt to apply non-function***. Also just double checking, I think there is a missing bracket the line below outp after }) _)_ I was only able to run it after adding this one.  Finally, the reason I am using SELECT *, is because I want all the column names , when I tried typing it in I got a syntax error. If I shall provide them all, would using  ***SELECT name, etc FROM table*** work ?

Comment: Actually there should not be an extra closing parentheses since I had an extra opening. Please try again with my edit and describe any error or undesired results not simply *it worked* or *it did not work*. Syntax error may be due to column names with spaces or special characters. Enclose such column names with double quotes using all lowercase.

Comment: I have copied your code and use it as is. I got the above error attached as image in the post. I had to adjust location = location(),  to  **location = location_pick ()**, but kept the rest the same as your code. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Error derives in UI section. See edits removing unneeded commas with small server fct fix.

Comment: Thanks, I did the edits. Now I am getting this error message **Error:'data' must be 2-dimensional (e.g. data frame or matrix)** , where can I convert my table from the database to a data frame?

Comment: Just noticed your `renderDataTable` did not properly separate from `renderPlot`. I edit with proper closing.

Comment: I tried the edits you suggested. Here is the error I got when I clicked on submit **Error in eval: attempt to apply non-function**.

Comment: Hmmm...testing code here, my R Shiny app powered by an SQLite database works great. [See my code](https://pastebin.com/zp3pRJM8). However, I did not use `pool` or `glue::glue_sql` but regular connection and `sqlInterpolate`. And my `ggplot` has more aesthetics. My guess is carefully test the `glue` query works on its own outside the Shiny app.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I think the syntax between SQLite and postgresql to query databases is slightly different based on reading about it online since I don't use it. Would you know of any example using multiple selector inputs to query a postgresql database??

Comment: Both interface with R's `DBI`. Again, your ui does not select multiple inputs but one choice per dropdown so your SQL can use `=` instead of `IN`. Try replacing `glue` with `sqlInterpolate`. See edit. Also, try regular connection object instead of `pool`.

Comment: Thank you @Parfait! You are a Gem. It worked like magic after I made the last changes you suggested. I am super thankful!